How to encode list of values with manually vocab inserted BertTokenizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kakao/.pyenv/versions/danke-feature-seq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2561, in __call__
    encodings = self._call_one(text=text, text_pair=text_pair, **all_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kakao/.pyenv/versions/danke-feature-seq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2667, in _call_one
    return self.encode_plus(
  File "/Users/kakao/.pyenv/versions/danke-feature-seq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2740, in encode_plus
    return self._encode_plus(
  File "/Users/kakao/.pyenv/versions/danke-feature-seq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py", line 652, in _encode_plus
    return self.prepare_for_model(
  File "/Users/kakao/.pyenv/versions/danke-feature-seq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 3219, in prepare_for_model
    encoded_inputs = self.pad(
  File "/Users/kakao/.pyenv/versions/danke-feature-seq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 3009, in pad
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: type of None unknown: <class 'NoneType'>. Should be one of a python, numpy, pytorch or tensorflow object.

I tried to encode my list of values with manually vocab inserted BertTokenizer. But got ValueError.
I manually inserted vocab with BertTokenizer in Transformers, for using recommendation task.
I build text_vocab.txt like,
3456
4567
5678

and I built empty BertTokenizer and insert vocab_file I made.
tokenizer = BertTokenizer(vocab_file="./test_vocab.txt")

and I would like to encode value list like
['3456', '4567', 5678']

But I got encode error. What is to problem?

use pretrained tokenizer. Add new tokens using bert.add_tokens. Here is an example:
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-uncased")
num_added_toks = tokenizer.add_tokens(["new_tok1", "my_new-tok2"])
You will need to resize model input (one-hot-encoding) layer after doing this. And basically fine-tune the model to make your tokens meaningful for the model.
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.add_tokens.example

but what if not using nlp pretrained tokens? I think it's a waste appendding tokens based on base tokens. Is there any useful ways to start all over with new tokens?

It is always worth to reusing existing embeddings. This is the topic related to transfer learning. Even if you are training model from scratch if there was already trained model it is better to reuse it.
